# Could use some help setting up and running knockd on Mac :)

Tags: macos, bash, knockd

I'm a total n00b when it comes to bash, but need to connect to a web server using a port knocking sequence. I've found http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock which looks promising, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

The thing I'm unclear on (for starters):
Do I need to have the source code installed? Or should the OSX client run on its own? (because source seems to say its a client too - so confused)

If anyone out there has experience with this and could walk me through it, I'd be much obliged!

many thanks,
-jennyb

Comment: The server already exists? It already has port knocking in front of it? You are simply trying to connect to that server (with your browser or whatever)?

Comment: Yes the server exists, but is protected. Since the client can't ID me by IP address, he asked that I use port knocking, and gave me a sequence to follow…the idea that I could then connect via FTP with my regular FTP client...

Comment: Then yes, you would need a knock client (either that one or any of the ones linked at the bottom of that page presumably). And you only need the source code if you need to build the client yourself. If you can get a pre-built binary then you don't need any source code. Have you checked homebrew?

Comment: Ok, so I downloaded the OSX client but haven't been successful using it. Homebrew? Rings a bell, but what's the relation? remember: n00b me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) by doing the following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

After homebrew is done installing, you can install packages on your system like this:

```
brew install packagename
```

In your case, you could do `brew install knock` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: You can skip straight to step 3 if you installed with homebrew

If you download the knock utility from [zeroflux](http://www.zeroflux.org/proj/knock/files/knock-macos.tar.gz).

1. Doubleclick the downloaded file to decompress it (or right click 
   and open with archive utility)
2. Open terminal (Applications/Utilities/Terminal), move knock to a reasonable path, so your shell can find it and make sure you own it so you can run it:

sudo mv Downloads/knock /usr/local/bin/knock

sudo chown $USER:admin /usr/local/bin/knock

3. Using knock client: (again in the terminal)

knock servername port_sequence or knock servername port:protocol
    port:protocol

```
knock ftp.client_server.com 1234 5679 443
or
knock ftp.client_server.com 1234:udp 5679:tcp 443:tcp
```

Now launch your ftp client and connect